# Webscraping moviemeter in R

Tags: r, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape the movie names, rating and year from moviemeter so I can compare it to imdb. I managed to get the imdb top 250 movies into a dataframe with title, rating, rank, year. But I don't seem to get the moviemeter running..

This is my code:

```
url <- rvest::html("https://www.moviemeter.nl/list/")
 scrapemoviemeter <- rvest::html_nodes(x = url, css = ".film_row")
 head(scrapemoviemeter)
 moviemeter <- rvest::html_text(scrapemoviemeter, trim = TRUE)
```

Now I have value of  moviemeter with

```
head(moviemeter)
[1] "4,42 (15202)1. The Shawshank Redemption (1994)"                                                    
[2] "4,36 (9761)2. The Godfather (1972)Alternatieve titel: Mario Puzo's The Godfather"
```

How do I get the data into a dataframe separated with the rating, title and year?

Comment: Scraping IMDB is a violation of their Terms of Service. So, if you got IMDB IDs from scraping IMDB, you violated their Terms of Service. MovieMeter has an API. There's an R package to work with the API - https://github.com/hrbrmstr/moviemeter and they also request citations/attribution when publishing any derivative work from their data.

Comment: @indian friends - Instead of proposing an edit to the answers below that removes all text you should delete the question

Comment: What happened to this question? It went from IMDB + MovieMeter & R to energy drink and Python. This question should be deleted. The OP does know the edit history is fully available, right?

Answer (score 1):

If you have the IMDB id's use the MovieMeter API vs scraping:

```
library(moviemeter) # devtools::install_github("hrbrmstr/moviemeter")
library(purrr)

imdb_ids <- c("tt1107846", "tt0282552", "tt0048199")

map_df(imdb_ids, function(x) {
  mm <- mm_get_movie_info(x)
  mm <- map(mm, ~. %||% NA)  # the javascript has nulls, so get rid of them
  mm[c(1:11)]                # remove posters, countries, genres, actors and directors
}) -> df

dplyr::glimpse(df)
## Observations: 3
## Variables: 11
## $ id                <int> 57161, 6465, 33351
## $ url               <chr> "https://www.moviemeter.nl/film/57161", "https://www.moviemeter.nl/film/6465", "https://www.moviemeter.nl/film/33351"
## $ year              <int> 2007, 2002, 1955
## $ imdb              <chr> "tt1107846", "tt0282552", "tt0048199"
## $ title             <chr> "Theft", "Riders", "Illegal"
## $ display_title     <chr> "Theft", "Riders", "Illegal"
## $ alternative_title <chr> NA, "Steal", NA
## $ plot              <chr> "Een naïeve dorpsjongen wordt verliefd op een crimineel. Guy was altijd een nette beschaafde jongen, wie had er ooi...
## $ duration          <int> 90, 83, 88
## $ votes_count       <int> 1, 293, 20
## $ average           <dbl> 2.00, 2.55, 3.42
```

If you are trying to compare IMDB top 250 with MovieMeter top 250 then you have to scrape since their API is pretty limited.

Remember to cite them in anything you make from this work and be wary of scraping IMDB. LinkedIn sued a bunch of scrapers in 2016 and folks are going to be taking intellectual property even more seriously in the coming months/years.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is easier to use xpaths. Try this

```
library(rvest)
library(stringi)

url <- rvest::html("https://www.moviemeter.nl/list/")
scores <- rvest::html_nodes(x = url, xpath = "/html/body/div[1]/div[4]/div/div[3]/*//span[@class='score']")
scores <- rvest::html_text(scores, trim = TRUE)
names <- rvest::html_nodes(x = url, xpath = "/html/body/div[1]/div[4]/div/div[3]/*//a[@class='tooltip']")
names <- rvest::html_text(names, trim = TRUE)
years <- rvest::html_nodes(x = url, xpath = "/html/body/div[1]/div[4]/div/div[3]//div[@class='film_row']/text() ")
years <- rvest::html_text(years, trim = TRUE)
years <- stri_extract(years, regex = "\\b\\d{4}\\b")
years <- years[!is.na(years)]

names <- unlist(names)
scores <- unlist(scores)
years <- unlist(years)

df <- cbind(names, scores, years)
df <- as.data.frame(df)
```